# Storing data for page in twig

Tags: post, stripe

I'm using `craft-stripecheckout` to accept payments on my site, but want to email the user with the custom fields **after** they have been redirected.

Easiest way to describe this is below:

Page 1 - User is asked for payment amount and other custom inputs such as age.

Page 2 - Confirmation of details is shown, and Stripe payment button appears.

Page 3 - User is redirected here via the plugin after payment is completed. *this is when the email is sent with custom fields, such as age*

What is the best way to store all of the POST data, and use it again on the confirmation page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing an intermediate solution.

I stored the serialized POST data in a record, with a unique identifier.

I passed the `unique_id` (a random md5 hash) to Stripe as metadata.

On the webhook, I used the `unique_id` to retrieve the POST data.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure how this plugin works, but in general the best way to do this is to rely on Webhooks.  You can listen for `charge.succeeded` events and send an email when those occur.  If you're not a programmer, you can always use something like Zapier or IFTTT to do this too.

:)  Hope that helps!

Comment: I’ve been doing that. The trouble is the custom fields, the webhook doesn’t send those details.